# Best RESTful strategy for keeping one model in a collection set to “primary”

Tags: rest, crud, cqrs

Im building a CRUD api for models shared across multiple applications. Each application has its own business logic.

I need to set a model to “primary” and simultaniously remove any such designation from other models.

My use case is that I have a “order” model that gets created and set to sold. Customer is the parent model and can have multiple orders. Multiple “orders” can be created but only one can be set to sold. An application may want to change which order is set to sold, or create a new order and set it to sold.

Im considering two approaches:

1. Create a resource in my CRUD api that will set a flag on an order to sold and simultaneously iterate through the other orders for the given customer and remove the Sold flag, using a uri like ‘POST /customers/{id}/orders/{id}/soldOrder’
2. Ask and rely on the application clients to GET the orders and Update the desired one to “sold” while setting the undesired ones to “unsold”

Im skeptical that option one is RESTful.

Answer (score 0):

> Im skeptical that option one is RESTful.

How would you do it with a web site?

You'd probably provide a form; there would be a list -- maybe a radio list, maybe a dropdown -- of orders, with the currently selected item indicating which item is currently "sold".  The user, to communicate a change to this information, would select a different item in the list, and click the submit button.  That would send an HTTP request to the endpoint described in the form.action element.  The server, receiving this request, would make the appropriate changes to the domain model.

That's [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm); the client and the server are coupled, not to each other, but a common understanding of the semantics of the messages that they exchange so that they can cooperate in a protocol.